# Spring MVC: Reference Model Field outside of Form?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

Is it possible to reference a Model/Command field **outside** the form in Spring MVC? We have this situation:

```
<div>
<!-- Need to get extraInfo from Model object here, before Form -->
Extra Info: ${model.extraInfo}
</div>

<!-- Form starts here -->
<form:form method="POST" commandName="model" action="/save">
..
</form:form>
```

Comment: A form view is still a view. You can use the model as in any other view.

Comment: You can do exactly what you have in your example